# Qualification Module

Tags: civimember

Is there an easy way to record the various qualification levels for members?  We have our own internal qualification and renewal system that determines some people's membership status.  It would be helpful to be able to record the date, place and trainer involved for each of our Members.  There are 6 levels of training.

Answer (score 3):

This can be very easily achieved using custom data –

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/

The first decision to make is where you would like to see this information, on the contact record or at a membership level.

If a member can have multiple membership types then the custom data set should be created at the membership level. This option will then allow you to record qualification details per membership.

To record –

Date use the Data and Input Field Type option -

[image]

Place / Location use the Alphanumeric Select option -

[image]

Training level use the Alphanumeric Select option -

[image]

To record trainer level you can either use the Alphanumeric Select option or if you have the trainers as contacts in CiviCRM then you can use the Contact Reference Autocomplete option and limit list to a group

[image]

Don’t forget to mark them as searchable for reporting purposes!

The end result when viewing the membership -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As Anil said you can use Custom Fields - but assuming someone may have multiple qualifications you would probably need to set your Field group/set to be MultiRecord.

Next issue is whether you create these on the Membership record or the Contact Record. I would argue in favour of the latter.

Lastly a third option is to Create an Activity Type for this since they already have Date fields etc and are quite appropriate to use for this type of purpose