# Qualifications data

Tags: civimember

Our organisation has an internal qualification structure.  I would like to be able to record qualification level, date, place and trainer for each 'member' of the organisation, preferably within CiviMember module.  Has somebody already done to save me having to 're-invent the wheel' by adding custom fields?

Comment: Hi I see you're new to stackexchange civicrm. Normally we don't ask small variations of the same question twice and just instead post a comment on the original answer. I'd suggest deleting this question and commenting on the original question at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/30852/qualification-module.

Comment: See my comments on other question. V unlikely there is something 'out there' that would be both generic enough to be useful that wouldn't still require you to configure something. Making Custom Fields, or custom Activity Types is pretty fast solution for what you need.